# Sparql without FROM keyword

Tags: database, semantics, semantic-web, sparql

Glad if someone can clarify.

I always read that SQL and SPARQL are very similar.
However, a lot of times i have seen sparql query without the FROM keyword.
You would assume that you have to query the datasource 'FROM' somewhere in the database 
like how SQL behaves.

Example

```
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name
WHERE 
{
    ?person foaf:name ?name .
}
```

How does it know where to look for? Like in SQL, look in Database1 - table1

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPARQL queries are execute against an **RDF dataset**, which has two parts:

- A single **default graph**: a set of triples with no name attached to them
- Zero or more **named graphs**: a set of triples identified by a name

You can specify the graph to query using the optional `FROM` or `FROM NAMED` clauses. Have a look at [Specifying RDF Datasets](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#specifyingDataset). If you omit those clauses, then the query is executed on the default graph.

---

Graphs and RDF dataset storage is implementation dependent. For example, using [Jena ARQ](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/) you use a `QueryExecutionFactory` and you can initialize it in two ways:

- passing a [`Model`](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html), which becomes the default graph on which queries are executed
- passing a [`Dataset`](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/Dataset.html), which can contain a single default graph and several named graphs

Code Examples for Jena ARQ are available [here](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/app_api.html). Other implementation may be different.

Comment: And where/how the default graph is stored?

Answer (score 2):

It's closer to "look in Database1, all tables".

As all the data in RDF is triples (or quads if you look at the world that way) you can query across everything you have in one go, without having to worry about schema differences.

Comment: Surely more like 'look in what Database1 considers the default table'?

Comment: Initially, i thought there's some default graph to look at if no 'FROM' is specified.

Comment: There is, the analogy is a bit weak. In many RDF systems the default graph is the entire system though, it's more about picking what parts of the system you want your query to range over.